# React-Native file viewer

Tags: react-native

Hello fellow developers,
I am looking for react native code for doc,pdf,ppt and xls viewer in mobile. I want to read these files from assets folder,local storage and also from url link. 
Can someone please share the code for the above requirement.please

Thanks in advance

[when I tried the code from this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-doc-viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVZqm.png)

Comment: People won't, they expect you to do some research and ask specific questions where we can help.

Comment: If you did please share what you did and we can add more to it. Also here is a package you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-doc-viewer

Comment: @johnDoe It is not just about that. Stackoverflow is not there to find software for you. It is there to help specific coding problems

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I have already done that and facing errors like these(see edit). By the way, you have also shared the link where other people did the work , not you.

Comment: Great, so please share the code and we will try to help in the best way possible 

Comment: @DhavalJardosh click the link in the edit which I have done. FYI, to find quick solution, copy the code and paste in snack and see the results. if it is running successfully , print screen and send me that image then I agree whatever u say.

Comment: I'm checking, btw try adding a comma before `filename`, let's see if that's the issue.

Comment: Btw the last publish of the library you're looking and is 2 years old(it's the same link that I shared as well.)
Try this new one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-viewer

Comment: @DhavalJardosh k let me try the new link code which you have sent and I wont say thank you until its get executed buddy

Comment: @DhavalJardosh just out of curiosity and I know its totally off topic, in snack.expo.io online editor, How can I open cmd?

Comment: I don't think you can, but if you want to add a package in snack, just add the package name in `package.json` and it will automatically add it for you.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh yes but for linking how can I do it? for example: react-native link react-native-fs, How can I type this command in snack.expo.io?

Comment: Not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon before the filename (after the base64) else the object is not complete
Like

```
//snip
base64: "{BASE64 STRING}", 
filename: "sample",
//snip
```